# Monitor doesn't turn on the first try, is power supply failure imminent?

Tags: display, power-supply

I been noticing for the last couple days that when I turn on my computer and then my monitor(22inch lcd) that my monitor does not turn on.

I push the "on" button and the blue light comes on but the screen is blank. I usually have to then restart my computer and then my monitor will show in the upper left hand corner a dialog bog that says "analog" and it is flickering.

Then everything goes to normal.

Thinking it is the power supply but at the same time the tower is a year old(it came with a power supply). So when I take that into consideration I am not sure.

Comment: What brand of monitor is it?  I know that some Samsung monitors have issues with sub-standard capacitors in their power supplies.  Fairly easy fix if you are competent with a soldering iron and have access to the parts needed.

Comment: Yes it is a Samsung. I think Samsung SyncMaster 226BW

Answer (score 0):

Check the power supply capacitors in the monitor.  The bad ones will be obvious as the will be swollen.  Hit up your local electronic parts store and pick up some replacements.  Be sure to write down what size and type you need.  Once you have the parts on hand, it should only take a bout 15 minute to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem when I use an HDMI cable. But when I use a DVI cable instead it works fine. I think it might have to do something with the handshake process of HDMI between the monitor and my PC. If the monitor is not turned on first the PC wont find any device to do the handshake with.